# Compile source code from ARMv5 to ARMv6

Tags: c, compilation

I had finished a source code for a software application and this works fine on a ARMv5 processor/device.

Can I recompile the same source code that the software is running on an ARMv6 processor/device?

Or must I change parts of the source code with it runs on an ARMv6 processor/device?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compiler for this architecture, ant you don't use the assembly, most probably everything will work as supposed.

The problem can be with code that written in assembly as some of commands may be specific for this particular architecture. In this case you will have to re-write these parts of code.